# how can I build bash hyperlink strings from json fields?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am getting some JSON data from the NYTimes API.  I can get things to this form:

```
"results": [
{
  "headline": "such and such",
  "url": "http://such.and.such.com",
  ...
},
{
  "headline": "so and so",
  "url": "http://so.and.so.com",
  ...
},
...
]
```

I want to echo 1 string for every object in the array, so that the string text displays the headline, and the string is clickable to the url.

I know how I want the string to be built:

`echo -e "\e]8;;$URL\a$TITLE\e]8;;\a"`

I can't figure out how to use `jq` to populate those variable portions of the string.

```
> echo $RESULTS | jq '.results[] | "\e]8;;\(.url)\a\(.title)\e]8;;\a"'
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\e"') at <top-level>, line 1:
.results[] | "\e]8;;\(.url)\a\(.title)\e]8;;\a"
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\a"') at <top-level>, line 1:
.results[] | "\e]8;;\(.url)\a\(.title)\e]8;;\a"
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\e"') at <top-level>, line 1:
.results[] | "\e]8;;\(.url)\a\(.title)\e]8;;\a"
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\a"') at <top-level>, line 1:
.results[] | "\e]8;;\(.url)\a\(.title)\e]8;;\a"
jq: 4 compile errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\e` and `\a` are not valid in a JSON string; to encode the escape and bell control characters, you need to use `\u001b` and `\u0007` respectively. You probably also want use the `-r` option to `jq` to make it output raw strings (rather than JSON-encoded).

I would also strongly recommend double-quoting shell variable references (to avoid weird effects from word splitting and wildcard expansion), and using lower- or mixed-case variable names to avoid conflicts with the many all-caps names that have special meanings or functions.

So something like this:

```
echo "$results" | jq -r '.results[] | "\u001b]8;;\(.url)\u0007\(.title)\u001b]8;;\u0007"'
```

Or, in bash (but not all other shells) you can use a here-string instead of `echo`:

```
jq -r '.results[] | "\u001b]8;;\(.url)\u0007\(.title)\u001b]8;;\u0007"' <<<"$results"
```

Comment: I did that once and it worked; trying again leads to ```jq: error (at <stdin>:xx): Cannot iterate over null (null)```

Comment: If I say ```jq -r '.results[]? | "\u001b]8;;\(.url)\u0007\(.title)\u001b]8;;\u0007"' <<<"$results"``` nothing prints.  Not sure why .results[] would return null... ```echo $results``` shows all the results I had before

Comment: @AaronParisi That's really strange. I don't have exactly the same `results` variable you have (and BTW I'd again recommend double-quoting it (`echo "$results"`), but for me it seems to work if I either leave off the `?` after `.results[]` (which shouldn't matter as long as there actually is an array there), OR leave off the `-r` option. I do not understand why either of those would matter here.

Comment: ... it was my bad, I mixed up some variables on my end; it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your original jq script using bash escape sequence `$` :

```
jq -r $'.results[] | "\e]8;;\(.url)\a\(.title)\e]8;;\a"' <<< "$results"
```

Here bash will convert `\e` to character `0x1b`.